# Invalid indentation in Jade and CodeIgniter 3

Tags: codeigniter, pug

I have some problem about Jade Inheritance. I have configured and followed all steps from github. Exactly everything was find which means I can use Jade syntax and create file with jade extension. Unfortunately I cannot not use extends layout in my view file although I have tried many time.

The error message always come:

```
Invalid indentation, you can use tabs or spaces but not both
```

Below are the whole messages:

```
An uncaught Exception was encountered

Type: Exception

Message: C:\xampp\htdocs\jade\application\views\layout.jade (1) : Invalid indentation, you can use tabs or spaces but not both

Filename: C:\xampp\htdocs\jade\application\vendor\kylekatarnls\jade-php\src\Jade\Parser.php

Line Number: 92

Backtrace:

File: C:\xampp\htdocs\jade\application\vendor\kylekatarnls\jade-php\src\Jade\Jade.php
Line: 87
Function: parse

File: C:\xampp\htdocs\jade\application\vendor\kylekatarnls\jade-php\src\Jade\Jade.php
Line: 171
Function: compile

File: C:\xampp\htdocs\jade\application\vendor\kylekatarnls\jade-php\src\Jade\Jade.php
Line: 97
Function: cache

File: C:\xampp\htdocs\jade\application\vendor\ci-jade\ci-jade\src\Jade.php
Line: 61
Function: render

File: C:\xampp\htdocs\jade\application\controllers\Welcome.php
Line: 35
Function: view

File: C:\xampp\htdocs\jade\index.php
Line: 292
Function: require_once
```

My controller:

```
<?php
defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');
//https://github.com/ci-jade/ci-jade
class Welcome extends CI_Controller {

      use Jade;

      public function index()
      {
        $this->settings([
      'cache' => TRUE
    ]);
        $this->view('myview', [
      'title' => 'My Jade View',
      'authors' => [
        'Luke',
        'Leia',
        'Lando'
      ]
    ]);
      }
}
```

My view file "myview.jade"

```
extends layout

block content
```

My view file layout.jade

```
!!! 5
html(lang='en')  // 2 indentation
  head
    block script
  body
    block content
     h1 Hello
```

The links I've followed

1- [github](https://github.com/ci-jade/ci-jade)

2- [jade](http://jade-lang.com/reference/inheritance/)

Comment: Please refer to this answer. In your template file, you have used tab and space for indention. Jade allows the use of ether tab or space for indention.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18343651/jade-indentation-errors

Comment: Yes, You are right. Thanks.